# Remove/replace multiple spaces using browser styles

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I was looking around a few forums about CSS questions but I couldn't find something specific enough, so here we go!

I use Jenkins and when I generate a production/test diff, it comes out with it's own formatting. Unfortunately because it uses spaces to split different columns within a table, extracting the data become kinda annoying (number of spaces differ depending on the amount of test).

Is there a way, by inputting CSS styles directly in my browser, to replace any multiple space occurrences by a ";"?

Here's a quick example to explain:

```
690621               0.25            None       None                 0
8701820               0.25            None       None                 0
```

and here's what I would like:

```
690621;0.25;None;None;0
8701820;0.25;None;None;0
```

Is it possible at all? and if so, what would be the best way to proceed? Ideally, it would be a solution that can be given in a process during training (something easy to copy and paste for instance).

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use JS?

Comment: Not with CSS..no I don't think so. CSS can't *replace* anything. It can only style what is there.  Is it inserting non-breaking spaces or something because normally will auto-collapse whitespace like that.

Comment: There are reasons why I can't edit the jenkins output itself (tool not owned by my company, among which).
But basically the html output contains the spaces : "<span class="timestamp"><b>06:15:57</b> </span>  19318622     4486620"

Since I can't actually edit it before, I was wondering if it was possible to get some modifications in the style so windows' clipboard would grab what I need in the right format, instead of having gazilions of spaces :) CSS seemed the easiest way to go for me, but if you have any other solution, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't do it with JS, you can sort of hack it by putting the code in a container, and setting the container's font size to "0".  Then set the font size of the elements to whatever size you want.

Then, use the `:after` pseudo selector to add the semicolons after each item.  Run the snippet below.

Note: Since all those spans of blank space have a class, you could also set the display to "none" for that class in the css.  The only problem there is that there would be one space between each item because they are separate inline elements.  If you don't mind one space (or if you would like one space) that would be another way to go.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
.kwd, .lit {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.kwd:not(:last-of-type):after, .lit:not(:last-of-type):after {
  content:';';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="lit">690621</span>
    <span class="pln">               </span>
    <span class="lit">0.25</span>
    <span class="pln">            </span>
    <span class="kwd">None</span><span class="pln">       </span>
    <span class="kwd">None</span><span class="pln">                </span>
    <span class="lit">0</span>
    <span class="pln"></span>
    <span class="lit">8701820</span>
    <span class="pln">               </span>
    <span class="lit">0.25</span>
    <span class="pln">            </span>
    <span class="kwd">None</span>
    <span class="pln">       </span>
    <span class="kwd">None</span>
    <span class="pln">                 </span>
    <span class="lit">0</span>
</div>
```